# Sharing code between classes with runtime versus compile-time parameters

Tags: c++, templates, code-reuse, code-duplication

Consider a class which simulates an associative cache:

```
template <size_t S, size_t L, size_t W>
class AssociativeCache {
  size_t which_set(size_t index) { return index % (L * W); }
  // ...
};
```

Here, the key cache parameters `S`, `L` and `W` are compile-time non-type template parameters.

One might also implement a similar class like this:

```
class AssociativeCacheDynamic {
  size_t S, L, L;
  size_t which_set(size_t index) { return index % (L * W); }
  // ...
};
```

Here, the key parameters are the same as the other case but are stored as as member variables of the class instead.

Except for a constructor which sets values of the cache parameters in the dynamic case, the implementation of every method the two classes is also essentially identical, i.e., the source code is byte-for-byte identical<sup>1</sup>.

If I want *both* of these classes, how can I implement them with the least code duplication and with as few grotty macro or multiple include hacks as possible?

Bonus points if the solution allows you to have *some* differences: e.g., the template method might use `std::array` storage and the dynamic one might use `std::vector`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although the compiled code will often be radically different (since the code is not specialized for fixed values in the dynamic case).

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to come up with base classes to encapsulate the differences between the two forms, while allowing a derived template class to hold the common functionality.  Something like:

```
#include <vector>

template <size_t Sp, size_t Wp, size_t Lp>
class AssociativeCacheTemplate {
protected:
    static constexpr size_t S = Sp;
    static constexpr size_t W = Wp;
    static constexpr size_t L = Lp;
    AssociativeCacheTemplate() { }
};

class AssociativeCacheDynamic {
protected:
    size_t S;
    size_t W;
    size_t L;
public:
    AssociativeCacheDynamic(size_t Sp, size_t Wp, size_t Lp): S(Sp), W(Wp), L(Lp) { }
};

template <class T>
class AssociativeCache: T {
    using T::L;
    using T::W;
    using T::S;
public:
    using T::T;
    size_t which_set(size_t index) const { return index % (L * W); }
};

int test() {
    AssociativeCache<AssociativeCacheTemplate<2, 16, 32>> t;
    AssociativeCache<AssociativeCacheDynamic> d(2, 16, 32);
    return t.which_set(3) * d.which_set(2);
}
```

The `static constexpr` in the template base allows the template values to be used as constants in the code, without taking up any memory.  And as long as the size variables `S`, `W`, and `L` are the same between the two bases, the `using` statements in the main `AssociativeCache` class will be able to access both base classes values.

The `public` for the `AssociativeCacheDynamic` constructor was necessary to get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be as follows:

```
size_t which_set_impl(size_t index, size_t line_length, size_t ways_per_set)
{
    return index % (line_length * ways_per_set);
}

template <size_t S, size_t L, size_t W>
class AssociativeCache
{
    public:
        size_t which_set(size_t index) { return which_set_impl(index, L, W); }
};

class AssociativeCache2
{
    size_t size, line_length, ways_per_set;
    public:
        AssociativeCache2(size_t line_length_in, size_t ways_per_set_in) : line_length(line_length_in), ways_per_set(ways_per_set_in) {}
        size_t which_set(size_t index) { return which_set_impl(index, line_length, ways_per_set); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AssociativeCache<10, 10, 10> MyCache1 = {};
    AssociativeCache2 MyCache2(10, 10);
    std::cout << "1: " << MyCache1.which_set(10) << " and 2: " << MyCache2.which_set(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can have both Associative Caches extend from a base class which exposes the members, ex:

```
    class BaseCache
    {
        virtual size_t GetLineLength() = 0;
        virtual size_t GetWaysPerSet() = 0;
        size_t which_set(size_t index) { return index % (this->GetLineLength() * this->GetWaysPerSet());
    }
    class AssociativeCacheFoo : BaseCache
    {
        ...
        size_t GetLineLength() const final override { return line_length; }
    }
    template <size_t S, size_t L, size_t W>
    class AssociativeCacheBar : BaseCache
    {
       ...
        size_t GetLineLength() const final override { return L; }
    }
```

The example directly above is pseudo code, untested, and not guaranteed to compile.

And expose the implementation to a helper function either through making these accessors public or by making which_set a friend function to both of them.

Comment: This doesn't share the code between `AssociativeCache` and `AssociativeCache2` really: every method has to be written differently in each class, it's just factors out the implementation to another method which can be called by both, but I don't want to write each method separately. Also, it relies heavily on the compiler to inline and constant propagate the values in the template case, or else you might get bad code.